# Failed to resolve: fragment after adding navigation

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

I got this error when I try to add dependencies for `Navigation`

> Failed to resolve: fragment

I have add those lines:

```
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navigationVersion"
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$navigationVersion"
```

In project gradle this is what I add:

```
ext{
    navigationVersion = '1.0.0-alpha09'
}
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
```

I tried to invalidate cache & restart and It didn't work.

Side note I have migrated to `androidx` with no problem but after I tried to add the `Navigation` library, this error appears

Comment: Do you have the `enableJetifier` option in your `gradle.properties` as per [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate#migrate)?

Comment: yes I have `android.enableJetifier=true` along with `android.useAndroidX=true` in the `gradle.properties`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, set `navigationVersion = '2.0.0'` is OK

Answer (score 12):

I found the same problem when trying to use the code that i found on the Udacity lecture.

```
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navigationVersion"
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$navigationVersion"
```

The problem is that I am using the AndroidX, I need to change the the group name of these dependencies from `android.arch.navigation` into `androidx.navigation`

```
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navigationVersion"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$navigationVersion"
```

detail information describes here: https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the code as below

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation

```
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navigationVersion"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$navigationVersion"
```

```
ext{
    navigationVersion = '2.1.0-rc01'
}
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
```

Comment: rc means release candidate, why is this answer better than the previous?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this problem too, I had connection problems and it could not download the dependencies.

- Cleaned project
- Solved connection problems
- Restarted android studio

and now all is fine.

Comment: I just used the older version and It works. At this time latest version is 2.4.2 and I'm using 2.2.2 now. The restart wasn't helpful. Thanks